# How destructure an object starting from a constant?

Tags: javascript

I have a `utils/constant.js` file with:

```js
// Key of total elements in remote collection
export const TOTAL_ELEMENTS = "totalElements";
```

I need to access to `totalElements` via the constant.

```js
import { TOTAL_ELEMENTS } from "./constants.js";
[...]
let data = {
    content: "foo",
    totalElements: 54
};

if(TOTAL_ELEMENTS in data) {
    // pseudocode, of course it doesn't work.
    // of course in my case need to return 54
    const { TOTAL_ELEMENTS } = data;
    return TOTAL_ELEMENTS;
}
```

Comment: I understand that OP needs to access `54` without actually typing `totalElements` & rather by using the value from the constant `TOTAL_ELEMENTS`. So, something like: `data[TOTAL_ELEMENTS];`. @sineverba - is it not simpler to just do `if (TOTAL_ELEMENTS in data) return data[TOTAL_ELEMENTS];`

Comment: As already noted, you don't need destructuring in this case. But if you did you would need to use [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) notation and provide an alias for the destructured variable name. `const { [TOTAL_ELEMENTS]: totalElementsAlias } = data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired objective is:

- use the constant `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` (& not directly the prop-name)
- check if `data` has the corresponding prop
- if found, then return the value of the prop

The below code-sample may be one solution to achieve the desired objective:

`if (TOTAL_ELEMENTS in data) return data[TOTAL_ELEMENTS];`

**NOTE**
The above does not `de-structure` the data. It access the corresponding prop directly without the need to destructure.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
As [@pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) mentioned, using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` is a better way of doing this in case the value is falsy:

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty(TOTAL_ELEMENTS)) {
  return data[TOTAL_ELEMENTS]
}
```

**Original answer:**
While the answer [@jsN00b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13658816/jsn00b) provided works and is closer to OP's [@sineverba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333012/sineverba) code, there's an issue here since the `in` operator [checks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for the specified property in both the specified object *AND* its prototype chain.

This means that, for example, if `data`s prototype is `Object.prototype`, something like `'toString' in data` would work as well.

For that reason, you could use something like the following to only check for the `'totalElements'` key in the object itself, and avoid destructuring:

```
if (data[TOTAL_ELEMENTS]) {
  return data[TOTAL_ELEMENTS]
}
```

Comment: This fails if the value is falsy, better to use [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) or the new [`hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)

Comment: @pilchard good point, I forgot all about that. Thanks!